# WSO2 ESB call not passing envelope

Tags: wso2, esb

I have an API of the form

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="MyRestApi" context="/practice">
<resource methods="GET" uri-template="/{someValue}">
    <inSequence>
    <header name="Action" value="urn:sayHello"/>
    <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
        <format>
            <p:sayHello xmlns:p="http://practice">
                <p:inputString>$1</p:inputString>
            </p:sayHello>
        </format>
        <args>
           <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:uri.var.someValue"/>
        </args>
    </payloadFactory>
    <log level="full"/>
    <call>
        <endpoint>
           <address uri="http://192.168.0.105:9763/services/Practice/sayHello" format="soap12"/>
        </endpoint>
    </call>
    <enrich>
        <source type="body" clone="true"/>
        <target type="property" action="child" property="body_of_first_call"/>
    </enrich>
    <property xmlns:ns="http://practice" name="response" expression="//ns:return" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
    <property xmlns:ns="http://practice" name="response2" expression="//ns:sayHelloResponse" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
    <log>
        <property name="myValue" expression="$ctx:response"/>
        <property name="myValue2" expression="$ctx:response2"/>
        <property name="myValue3" expression="$ctx:body_of_first_call"/>
    </log>
    <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
        <format>
            <result>
                <sentValue>$1</sentValue>
                <returnedValue>$2</returnedValue>
            </result>
        </format>
        <args>
            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:uri.var.someValue"/>
            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:response"/>
        </args>
    </payloadFactory>
    <property name="messageType" value="application/xml" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
    <respond/>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence/>
    <faultSequence/>
</resource>
</api>
```

Based almost entirely on a guide found [here](http://dakshithar.blogspot.com/2014/05/entity-aggregation-with-wso2-esb-and_14.html)

It's at this point just an attempt to grasp the concepts of connectors and APIs so I can apply it to what I'm doing at work, but I've hit a snag. Any attempts to communicate with an outside SOAP service, which my ESB will need to do, either fails to find the endpoint or fails to pass on the values in the SOAP envelope.

As written above the code will find the endpoint, but the input value inputString in the request is always null. It's essentially identical to putting that address into your browser which completely omits the SOAP envelope, however logging the call prints the envelope as expected to the console so the envelope is being generated but not making its way to the application server.

Things I have also tried:

1) Changing the endpoint address to be the service endpoint, rather than the specific operation. This causes an error from the AS claiming the operation cannot be found. This endpoint and operation work as expected in SoapUI.

2) Using a WSDL endpoint instead of address. Result is the same as in 1.

3) Adding/removing the header tag. All three endpoints have been tried with/without the header tag. Their results do not change.

At this point I've exhausted my admittedly poor understanding of ESBs.

Answer (score 2):

To invoke my service I set up my mediator this way.

```
<call blocking="true">
  <endpoint>
   <address uri="http://169.254.193.10:9769/services/ServicePharmacy" format="soap11"/>
  </endpoint>
</call>
```

the blocking property in true is to do synchronous messaging

```
<call blocking="true">

</call>
```

this is my API

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="showByIdCallMediator" context="/getByIdCall">
   <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/{Id}">
      <inSequence>
         <property name="getId" expression="get-property('uri.var.Id')" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
         <log>
            <property name="ID" expression="get-property('getId')"/>
         </log>
         <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format>
               <p:searchPharmacy xmlns:p="http://pharmacy.arce.org">
                  <ax22:pharmacy xmlns:ax22="http://pharmacy.arce.org">
                     <xs:id xmlns:xs="http://pharmacy.arce.org/xsd">$1</xs:id>
                  </ax22:pharmacy>
               </p:searchPharmacy>
            </format>
            <args>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('getId')"/>
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>         
         <header name="Action" scope="default" value="urn:searchPharmacy"/>         
         <call blocking="true">
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="http://169.254.193.10:9769/services/ServicePharmacy" format="soap11"/>
            </endpoint>
         </call>
         <log>
            <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="Status" expression="get-property('axis2','HTTP_SC')"/>
         </log>
         <log level="full"/>
         <enrich>
            <source type="body" clone="true"/>
            <target type="property" property="Ouput_Respose_Service"/>
         </enrich>
         <log level="custom" separator=",">
            <property name="Service_Response" expression="get-property('Ouput_Respose_Service')"/>
         </log>
         <respond description=""/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
      <faultSequence>
         <sequence key="{faultSEQ}"/>
      </faultSequence>
   </resource>
</api>
```